# What is the difference between Azure Devops AzurePowerShell@4 and AzurePowerShell@5 tasks?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-release-task

I have some existing ADO YAML pipelines. They are using `AzurePowerShell@4` task. But the latest version of this task is `AzurePowerShell@5` . I have checked on the internet but I couldn't find their difference.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can see the code of `AzurePowerShell@4` [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShellV4), and of `AzurePowerShell@5` [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShellV5).

Accurint to the code the `@5` created because of [this](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11672) issue.

Over time it seems that version 4 is also updated and maintained, not sure there is much different, but just check the code :)

Comment: Thanks @shayki, your remark to 'this issue' solved my problem too. By using  `AzurePowerShell@5`  I overcame my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73950059/ado-release-pipeline-azurepowershell-task-fails-on-connect-azaccount